# pure C: Dialogue default handling of Ctrl+C messages

Tags: c, winapi

Standard Windows message boxes have a functionality of copying their contents on pressing Ctrl+C to clipboard.
Ok, I decided to try doing this myself.

Here is my dialogue resource:

```
IDD_MAIN DIALOGEX 0,0,500,250 STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_VISIBLE
CAPTION "Information"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg",0,0,0x1
    {   LTEXT   "I strongly recommend you to move all your user folders to disk D\:",ID_INFOTEXT,10,10,100,100
        CHECKBOX    "&Do not show this dialogue again",ID_SHOWSTATE,10,120,100,15
        DEFPUSHBUTTON   "&Ok",IDOK,273, 148, 100, 15
    }
```

Dialogue is created quite fine, everything works fine too.
Checkbox is checked/unchecked as expected, and Ok closes the dialogue.

Now when you press Ctrl+C you hear an ugly  beep.
I have tryed to handle the Ctrl+C in dialogue proc, but keystrokes do not go there at all.
Now I have used a `WM_GETDLGCODE` in a subclassed control window proc, but also with no result - could not get rid that ugly beep and Ctrl+C does not go there too.

Ok, I have replaced a windowProc for a dialogue, but still no result - the ugly beep is in place and no Ctrl+C there.

So the question at the very end is where does that ugly beep  come from by default? Any special message handle somewhere in `DefWindowProc`? 
Where can I handle it finally and replace handler?

P. S. No MFC, no startup code, no .net, pure C and WinAPI only.

Comment: Your absolutely very first action at Stack Overflow should be to take the [tour]. No excuses.

Comment: Isn't there an "or" (`|`) missing in the style defintion?

Comment: IInspectable, done. I do not see if I have broken any traditions with my post, did I?

Comment: alk, they are in place and I can read them, so they seem not to be eaten.

Comment: I guess alk means the `|` you edited out of `DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP`.

Comment: Weather Vane, sorry, my bad. Corrected. Have not noticed from the very beginning.

Comment: Are you using DialogBox or CreateDialog?

Comment: I feel this works out of the box with the WinAPI function `MessageBox()` only.

Comment: Anders, CreateDialog. Does it matter?

Comment: alk, exactly! This why I have to do it myself for a dialogue.

Comment: Which Windows version do you use?

Comment: alk, Windows 7. Generally it is a investigation project to do similar thing in the future real projects.

Comment: Yes it does matter, if it was DialogBox you would probably have to hook.

Comment: Anders, got it. Fortunately I have started playing from CreateDialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog manager treats `MessageBox` based dialogs in a special way and sends them a `WM_COPY` message so it can fill the clipboard.

The beep comes from `IsDialogMessage` because the child control with the keyboard focus does not want the keyboard input.

To catch the Ctrl+C keypress and avoid the beep you must process keyboard messages before calling `IsDialogMessage`. You could call [`TranslateAccelerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646373(v=vs.85).aspx) or do your own custom handling:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT Msg, WPARAM Wp, LPARAM Lp)
{
    switch(Msg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hDlg);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_COPY:
        MessageBoxA(hDlg, "TODO: Set clipboard content here", 0, 0);
        break;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

BOOL IsKbdCopyMessage(HWND hDlg, MSG*pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_CHAR && pMsg->wParam == VK_CANCEL)
    {
        LRESULT dlgcod = SendMessage(pMsg->hwnd, WM_GETDLGCODE, pMsg->wParam, 0);
        if (!(dlgcod & (DLGC_WANTMESSAGE|DLGC_WANTCHARS)))
        {
            SendMessage(hDlg, WM_COPY, 0, 0);
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

...WinMain(...) 
{
    MSG msg;
    HWND hDlg = CreateDialog(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAIN), NULL, DlgProc);
    while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        if (IsKbdCopyMessage(hDlg, &msg)) continue;
        if (IsDialogMessage(hDlg, &msg)) continue;
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*The dialog manager treats `MessageBox` based dialogs in a special way and sends them a `WM_COPY`*" Interesting, but is this documented somewhere? I am asking because [`WM_COPY`s documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649022(v=vs.85).aspx) just states: "*An application sends the WM_COPY message to an edit control or combo box [...]*"

Comment: Anders, an excellent description and an excellent idea. I shall give it a try. Thank you. Do I understand correctly, that no MessageBox specifics can be used in an ordinary dialogue handling?

Comment: No I don't think it is documented anywhere that MessageBox is special inside the internals of DialogBox. You cannot use this feature in your own code.

Comment: Maybe I spoke too soon, @ https://github.com/mirror/reactos/blob/master/reactos/win32ss/user/user32/windows/messagebox.c you can see a call to NtUserxSetMessageBox and I assume Windows does something similar but it is not a good idea to depend on undocumented things like these and you don't know what other special things are done to a MessageBox. You don't gain much because you still have to handle WM_COPY on your own.

Comment: Anders, you are right. I meant well documented approach.

Answer (score -1):

One way to detect Ctrl-C could be to on receiving a [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx) passing a `0x43` ([virtual key-code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx) for the C-key) as `wParam` call [`GetAsyncKeyState()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx) and test its result for having `VK_CONTROL` set.

You could avoid calling call [`GetAsyncKeyState()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx) by tracking the Ctrl-keys' states yourself by also monitoring `WM_KEYUP` messages, for the relevant "virtual key-code".

Comment: I have tryed doing it this way, but it seems that default processing goes somehow different. WM_KEYDOWN seems to be handled somehow, but that ugly beep does not go away, though I do not call DefWindowProc.

Comment: "*ugly beep*" Check the dialogue's parent window's message function.

Comment: alk, no. Dialogue is the only general window in this app. No parent. Generally the Ctrl+C can be handled in one of three spaces, as I understand: DialogProc, DefWindowProc and control DefProc.

Comment: It's unclear, why you are calling `GetAsyncKeyState` to determine the *synchronous* key state of a modifier.